# Resource limit on azure self hosted agent

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I have set real time user priority in */etc/security/limits.conf* and added user to this group. On self hosted agent running ubuntu and agent as service; I see rt prio as 90

```
:~$ ulimit -r
90
```

But when i check from pipeline the limit is 0

```
- task: Bash@3
  inputs:
    targetType: 'inline'
    script: |
      echo "ulimits : $(ulimit -r)"
      whoami
```

User name is printed same as on agent machine shell but real-time prio is 0 instead of 90.

How can i make the pipeline shell resource values same as seen on machine shell ?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the agent is managed by systemd, the resource limits directive can be set in the unit file at

```
/etc/systemd/system/vsts.agent.xxx
```